# Safely down casting from Int to Int8 in Swift

Tags: json, swift, integer, type-conversion

I receive a set of integers via an api json response (which I convert into a `[String: Any]` dictionary). These integers are guaranteed to be in the range-10...-10 (inclusively). In my model I'd like to store these as `Int8`.

This is how I'm converting my json dictionary to it's model object but I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of ensuring the ints in the json actually fit in an `Int8`?

```
func move(with dict: JSONDictionary) -> Move? {
    if let rowOffset = dict[JSONKeys.rowOffsetKey] as? Int,
       let colOffset = dict[JSONKeys.colOffsetKey] as? Int {

      if let rowInt8 = Int8(exactly: rowOffset),
         let colInt8 = Int8(exactly: colOffset) {

        return Move(rowOffset: rowInt8, colOffset: colInt8)
      }
      else {
        print("Error: values out of range: (row: \(rowOffset), col: \(colOffset)")
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Missing key, either: \(JSONKeys.rowOffsetKey) or \(JSONKeys.colOffsetKey)")
    }

    return nil
  }
```

Note that doing the following always fails regardless of the value of the incoming ints:

```
if let rowOffset = dict[JSONKeys.rowOffsetKey] as? Int8,
   let colOffset = dict[JSONKeys.colOffsetKey] as? Int8 {
...
```

This is how I'm converting the incoming json to a dictionary. The json in question is deeply nested and contains several different types.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: Any]
let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? JSONDictionary
```

Comment: Could you please show how you're creating the `JSONDictionary`? The cast `as? Int8` should work fine provided the values are `NSNumber`s that didn't originate from a Swift (non `Int8`) to Obj-C bridge – although for `NSNumber`s with values out of range for an `Int8`, the extra bits will be truncated.

Comment: Updated to answer your question.

Comment: Huh, weird that `as? Int` doesn't work in your case then (although in any case, you've stated that you don't want truncating behaviour, so you won't want to use it anyway) – but [this example demonstrates](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/5a673c23c5346c420588e9dd7d171228) that the cast should work.

Comment: Actually, your example fails too (without the `Any` cast): [example](https://gist.github.com/rmangino/b0fb9e7e738bb20d749fd490bdea592c)

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Your example works for me.

Comment: "Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)"

Comment: Hmm, okay could be a Swift 3.0 issue then – works fine for me in both Swift 3.0.2 and Swift 3.1

Comment: Cool - thanks for your help @Hamish!

Comment: Conversion from `NSNumber` to `Int8` is a part of [SE-0139](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md), and implemented in Swift 3.0.1.

Answer (score 14):

Here are some options for converting your `Int` (which is coming from an `NSNumber`) into an `Int8`:

**Just converting with `Int8`'s initializer `init(_: Int)`**

If your `Int` values are *guaranteed* to fit into an `Int8`, then converting them with `Int8(value)` is fine.

If you get an `Int` that doesn't fit in an `Int8`, your program will crash:

```
let i = 300
let j = Int8(i)  // crash!
```

**Initializing with `Int8`'s initializer `init(truncatingIfNeeded: BinaryInteger)`**

For a bit of extra safety, you should use the `init(truncatingIfNeeded: BinaryInteger)` initializer:

```
let i = 300
let j = Int8(truncatingIfNeeded: i)  // j = 44
```

This does generate altered values which might not be desirable, but it would prevent a crash.

**Explicitly checking the range of valid values**

As another alternative, you could just check the range explicitly:

```
if (-10...10).contains(i) {
    j = Int8(i)
} else {
    // do something with the error case
}
```

The advantage of checking is that you can specify the valid range instead of just detecting an error when the range exceeds the values that will fit in an `Int8`.

**Initializing with `Int8`'s initializer `init(exactly: Int)`**

Your code is currently using this method of safely initializing the `Int8` values.  This is robust since it will return `nil` if the value does not fit in an `Int8`.  Thus it can checked with *optional binding* as you are doing, or it can be combined with the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to provide default values if you have appropriate ones:

```
// Determine Int8 value, use 0 if value would overflow an Int8
let j = Int8(exactly: i) ?? 0
```

**Directly casting `NSNumber` with `as Int8` in [Swift 3.0.1](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md) and above**

As @Hamish and @OOPer mentioned in the comments, it is now possible to cast an `NSNumber` directly to `Int8`.

```
let i: NSNumber = 300
let j = i as Int8  // j = 44
```

This does have the same truncating effect as using `init(truncatingIfNeeded: BinaryInteger)`.

In conclusion, your current code is safe, and probably is the best solution for your problem unless you would like to detect when the values exceed the current desired range of `-10...10`, in which case explicitly checking would be the better option.

Comment: Currently the api I'm using only returns values in the range of -10...-10 but that could change in the future. Wouldn't `(Int8.min...Int8.max).contains(i)` be better? Also, I'm not sure why `init(truncatingBitPattern: Int)` would be better/safer than `Int8(exactly: Int)` since I do not want the truncating behavior.

Comment: I updated my answer.  It incorporates the information from the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much - this is a fantastic resource for others who might have wondered why the basic (intuitive) `Int8` cast fails. Personally, I upgraded to Swift 3.0.1.

Comment: truncatingBitPattern is renamed to truncatingIfNeeded now.

Comment: Another (less known?) option is `numericCast`. It is a generic function and comes in handy if you need to pass a Swift integer to a C function and you “know” that it fits into the target type.

Answer (score 2):

As said @vacawama

```
let j = Int8(exactly: i) ?? 0
```

is a perfect and safe way to convert Int to UInt8, but sometimes I need to get max and min values of UInt8 instead of zero. I'm using extension:

```
extension UInt8 {

    /// Safely converts Int to UInt8, truncate remains that do not fit in UInt8.
    /// For instance, if Int value is 300, UInt8 will be 255, or if Int value is -100, UInt8 value will be 0
    init(truncateToFit int: Int) {
        switch int {
        case _ where int < UInt8.min: self.init(UInt8.min)
        case _ where int > UInt8.max: self.init(UInt8.max)
        default: self.init(int)
        }
    }

    /// Safely converts Float to UInt8, truncate remains that do not fit in UInt8.
    /// For instance, if Float value is 300.934, UInt8 will be 255, or if Float value is -100.2342, UInt8 value will be 0
    init(truncateToFit float: Float) {
        switch float {
        case _ where float < Float(UInt8.min): self.init(UInt8.min)
        case _ where float > Float(UInt8.max): self.init(UInt8.max)
        default: self.init(float)
        }
    }

    /// Safely converts Double to UInt8, truncate remains that do not fit in UInt8.
    /// For instance, if Double value is 300.934, UInt8 will be 255, or if Double value is -100.2342, UInt8 value will be 0
    init(truncateToFit double: Double) {
        switch double {
        case _ where double < Double(UInt8.min): self.init(UInt8.min)
        case _ where double > Double(UInt8.max): self.init(UInt8.max)
        default: self.init(double)
        }
    }
}
```

For instance:

```
    let value = UInt8(truncateToFit: Int.max) // value == 255
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm found standard realization for all numbers conform to BinaryInteger protocol, such that Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, and so on.

```
let value = UInt8(clamping: 500) // value == 255
let secondValue = UInt8(clamping: -500) // secondValue == 0
```

But for Double and Float, there is elegance solution, one extension for all BinaryInteger types

```
extension BinaryInteger where Self: FixedWidthInteger {

    /// Safely converts Float to BinaryInteger (Uint8, Uint16, Int8, and so on), truncate remains that do not fit in the instance of BinaryInteger range value.
    /// For instance, if Float value is 300.934, and self is UInt8, it will be 255, or if Float value is -100.2342, self value will be 0
    init(truncateToFit float: Float) {
        switch float {
        case _ where float < Float(Self.min): self.init(Self.min)
        case _ where float > Float(Self.max): self.init(Self.max)
        default: self.init(float)
        }
    }

    /// Safely converts Double to BinaryInteger (Uint8, Uint16, Int8, and so on), truncate remains that do not fit in the instance of BinaryInteger range value.
    /// For instance, if Double value is 300.934, and self is UInt8, it will be 255, or if Float value is -100.2342, self value will be 0
    init(truncateToFit double: Double) {
        switch double {
        case _ where double < Double(Self.min): self.init(Self.min)
        case _ where double > Double(Self.max): self.init(Self.max)
        default: self.init(double)
        }
    }
}
```

For instance:

```
let valueUInt16 = UInt16(truncateToFit: 5000000.0) // valueUInt16 == 65535
let valueInt8 = Int8(truncateToFit: 5000000.0)  // valueInt8 == 127
let valueUInt8 = UInt8(truncateToFit: -500.0)   // valueUInt8 == 0
```